# How can I select files from PC in the file explorer using robot framework?

Tags: python, robotframework

I have a button for Import which when clicked opens the windows file explorer from which we should select an excel file, which will then be imported. I cannot use seleniumlibrary since it has windows automation as well. I have the autoIT library, but how can i use it on a web page already brought open by selenium2library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try "Choose File" Keyword in SeleniumLibrary.

You can find the details in below link
http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Choose%20File

Comment: This doesn't work. The test passes, but the form doesn't get data.

Answer (score 0):

So, after many trials, The choose File worked.
It should be noted that choose file keyword accepts only an input type locator to it. The tag my element had was button. In my case however there was a hidden input element. It seems that in cases where file upload happens, an input type element has to be given in my application.

```
Choose file  //input[@hidden='true']  mypathToExcel
```

The above code worked for me where mypathToExcel is the path to my excel file.